# Check/Display value of variable via json in interval of 10ms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make a progress circle using jquery knob and php.
Jquery knob should get the value via ajax/json of the variable from php that is counting the iterations
With this php script I am getting the percentage of the total iteration that had been done.
The idea is to get with jquery, the number from here json_encode($percentage) every 20 ms. So it appears like a progress circle and fullfill it with color based on the number that gets from the json_encode($percentage)
Please help me I am a noob in jquery but I know a bit of php.

PHP

```
$urls1 is an array;
$counter = 0;
$total = count($urls1); 
foreach ($urls1 as $urls) {
  $counter++;
  $percentage = ($counter/$total) * 100;
  echo json_encode($percentage);
  // some morethings to do
}
```

Now Jquery

```
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
$(function () {
    jQuery_1_11_0('#check').on('submit', function (e) {
        var validatef = $("#url").val();
        var validaterror = $('#errorvalidate');
        if (validatef == 'Enter Domains Separated By New Line -MAX 100 DOMAINS-') {
            validaterror.text('Please enter domain names in the text area');
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            validaterror.text('');
            $("#progressbar").knob({
                'draw': function () {
                    /*$.ajax({
                        url: 'multipr-process.html', // it's acually php, but i am using htaccess code, it works fine tested on other scripts.
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: data,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                            //console.log(result['percentage']);
            var currentpercentage = result['percentage'];
            I want the result to get it every 20 ms and I believe that I need to place it in a variable, so
            I can add it beyond....
                        }
                    });*/
        //// if I enable this, ajax script above brokes and can't check in the console because it's reloading page.
                    $(this.i).val(currentpercentage + '%');
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'lib/multipr-process.html',
                data: $('#check').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data); // apple
                    $("#progressbar").knob().hide();
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        } // ending the else
    });
});
```

Comment: echo json_encode($percentage) in a loop will send you multiple json encoded data you need to move it out of loop.

Comment: @Faraz Exactly will send multiple data and I need to take with ajax/json the current amount of data it had taken, by updating it on screen, just like a progress circle will do.

Comment: Why use an AJAX server call? Why not a javascript URL/percentage/counter function?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I am a rookie in this, and this felt to be the simplest way for me. I know it's possible but could not get it done.

Comment: Do you need a call to the server to get the $urls1 array?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles The $urls1 array comes from a post via ajax. It's like a form where a user writes some urls and receives some details about each one. I think I specified in the second ajax.( type: 'post',....

Comment: @user3650099 jQuery success function will only be called when data is fully received by ajax request. you need to store percent processed in session variable and print it in another php file and read it by 2nd ajax request and show progress bar.

Comment: @Faraz OMG that sounds very complex, was thinking that ajax can clear old value and get new value. I heard about session scoping but it's problematic when you are in a share server, I believe you need shared scoping which on some companies of hosting is not granted or smth like that.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what your purpose is here or how your $urls1 is composed, but this comes to mind as as possibility, at least inspiration:

PHP simply returns:

```
echo json_encode($urls1);
```

AJAX success function:

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#progressbar").knob().hide();

  var total = data.length;
  var counter = 0;        
  var dt = setInterval(function() {
    if ( !data[counter] ) { clearInterval(dt); }
    else { $("#result").html((counter/total) * 100); }
    //else { console.log(data[counter]); }
    counter++;
  }, 2000); // slowed down, if works set to 20

 }
```